# setting content type for static javascript files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mime-types, es6-modules

I am using `express` to serve up a page with js files using es6 modules.
About es6 modules - https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

my server.js file is -

```js
const app = express();
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/src' ));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
    
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080!'));
```

and my index.html is -

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./src/test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the file `test.js` i am using es6 modules, thus the `type="module"` in the script tag.

But `test.js` script is not loading when i serve this html in browser. It is giving the error -

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I tried adding the mime type for js files in express using this in the `server.js` file  -

```
express.static.mime.define({'application/javascript': ['js']});
```

But still the same result. I guess i need to somehow send the mime/content-type from express for js files, but how?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needed a mount path.  `'/src'` in -

```
app.use( '/src', express.static( __dirname + '/src' ) );
```

not sure why though. will update.

Comment: Any way to get around this using the root mount path?

Answer (score 1):

The content type should be automatically determined by the file extension.

```
<script type="module" src="./src/test.js"></script>
```

You probably want to remove `/src` from the script path if you don't want to mount the static directory to `/src` in your express app.