# How to serve static images/files with correct mime types on express server

Tags: node.js, express

I want to serve everything in `../assets` folder with correct mime-types.
Static images are served with [incorrect mime-types](http://prntscr.com/plzu4u).

Here is my server code:

```js
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const server = express();

if (process.env.mode === 'development') {
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const config = require('../webpack.config');
  const compiler = webpack(config);

  server.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath, 
    HotModuleReplacement: true
  }));

  server.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
  server.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const appIndex = path.resolve(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html');

    compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(appIndex, (err, result) => {
      if (err) next();
      res.end(result);
    });
  });
} else if (process.env.mode === 'production') {

  server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../assets')));
  server.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, '../public'), {
    enableBrotli: true
  }));  

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
  });
}

server.listen(process.env.port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on the port ${process.env.port}...`);
});
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
[root]
|..[assets]
|....[images]
|......[png]
|........[myImaage.png]
|..[server]
|....[server.js]
```

What I tried:

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../assets')));
server.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets')));
server.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../assets')));
```

Comment: Here's are some ideas for what could be wrong: [express.static serving wrong content type](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2220) and [Setting content type for static files in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046558/setting-content-type-for-static-javascript-files-in-express).  `express.static()` looks up the mime type by file extension so if it's getting something so obvious (a PNG file) wrong, then something is corrupted in either the express installation or the mime lookup.

Comment: Re-installed express. The problem is solved. TY.